# Loading Modal View Controllar on Main View Controller Programmatically 

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, modalviewcontroller

I am creating a Ipad Application ,and so i have a Splitview as the Root View and now i want to add a user Login Screen (using Modal VC) , but the Problem is that i want load the Modal VC at view Did Load , just like in Ipad Settings app , so any body did something similar to that , or  if anyone can suggest me something , Also i am using ARC and Stroyborads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try loading the view in `viewDidAppear`. Because the view isn't on screen yet in `viewDidLoad`, it conflicts with the other view you are trying to bring up.

```
(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self presentModalViewController:];
}
```

Hope it helps!